# i cannot fix "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"

Tags: java, exception, math, zero

This is my program. I cannot find anything wrong with it, but when im trying to run it there is an error saying im dividing by zero.

```
import acm.program.*;  
public class ReverseDigits extends Program {  
public void run(){
println("This program reverses the digits in an integer."); 
int n = readInt("Enter a positive integer: ");
int x = 10;  
int t = 1;
int total = 0;
 //Finds the number of digits
 while (n > 0){
    while (n % x != 0) {
        t = t + 1;
        x = x * 10;
}
}
//In case the number has one digit the new number is the same
if(t == 1) {
 total = n;
}
//Creating the new number
while (t > 1) {
      t=t-1;
      total = (total + ((( n / (10^t)) - ((n /  (10 ^ (t+1))) * 10 )) * 10));
     } 
  println("The reverse number is " + total); 
   }  
}
```

I'm getting this error while trying to run it but I cannot find the problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: What do you think `^` does?

Comment: `10^t` is zero for `t = 10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` - is a XOR opertion, not degree! You need `Math.pow(number, degree);`

Comment: Now i have another problem

total = (total+((( n / (Math.pow(10, t))) - ((n /  (Math.pow(10, (t+1)))) * 10 )) * 10));

"possible loss of precision" error

Comment: Yes, result of division in java have type "double". Change type of "total" to "double", or cast result of calculation to "int".

Comment: i really cant get that working...

Comment: i changed it to "double" but when i run it i get the / by zero error again!

Comment: i have no idea how it possible. Have you performed a complete stop a running program and restart it?

Comment: yeah i tried that. let me send u the code again

Comment: import acm.program.*;  
public class ReverseDigits extends Program {  
public void run(){
println("This program reverses the digits in an integer."); 
int n = readInt("Enter a positive integer: ");
int x = 10;  
int t = 1;
double total = 0;
 //Finds the number of digits
 while (n > 0){
    while (n % x != 0) {
        t = t + 1;
        x = x * 10;
}
}
//In case the number has one digit the new number is the same
if(t == 1) {
 total = n;
}
//Creating the new number
while (t > 1) {
      t=t-1;
   total = (total + ((( n / (Math.pow(10, t))) - ((n /  (Math.pow(10, (t+1)))) * 10 )) * 10));
...